# RMAN restoring datafile out of ASM

Tags: oracle, backup, rman, oracle-asm

Why is RMAN restoring the datafiles out of ASM and how to restore a backup into ASM?

Here is one output. The tablespace triscaltb was restored in `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/dbs/MISSING00013`

```
RMAN> report schema;

Report of database schema for database with db_unique_name TRISCALDB

List of Permanent Datafiles
===========================
File Size(MB) Tablespace           RB segs Datafile Name
---- -------- -------------------- ------- ------------------------
1    780      SYSTEM               YES     +DATA/TRISCALDB/DATAFILE/system.258.1016190249
3    600      SYSAUX               NO      +DATA/TRISCALDB/DATAFILE/sysaux.257.1016190057
4    135      UNDOTBS1             YES     +DATA/TRISCALDB/DATAFILE/undotbs1.260.1016190491
5    250      PDB$SEED:SYSTEM      NO      +DATA/TRISCALDB/FD9AC20F64D244D7E043B6A9E80A2F2F/DATAFILE/system.267.1016191021
6    5        USERS                NO      +DATA/TRISCALDB/DATAFILE/users.259.1016190489
7    510      PDB$SEED:SYSAUX      NO      +DATA/TRISCALDB/FD9AC20F64D244D7E043B6A9E80A2F2F/DATAFILE/sysaux.266.1016191021
8    260      TRISCALPDB:SYSTEM    NO      +DATA/TRISCALDB/FD9BD2B44413096FE043B6A9E80ABC28/DATAFILE/system.272.1016192445
9    520      TRISCALPDB:SYSAUX    NO      +DATA/TRISCALDB/FD9BD2B44413096FE043B6A9E80ABC28/DATAFILE/sysaux.271.1016192441
10   5        TRISCALPDB:USERS     NO      +DATA/TRISCALDB/FD9BD2B44413096FE043B6A9E80ABC28/DATAFILE/users.273.1016192445
11   1243     TRISCALPDB:EXAMPLE   NO      +DATA/TRISCALDB/FD9BD2B44413096FE043B6A9E80ABC28/DATAFILE/example.270.1016192435
13   0        TRISCALTB            NO      /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/dbs/MISSING00013

List of Temporary Files
=======================
File Size(MB) Tablespace           Maxsize(MB) Tempfile Name
---- -------- -------------------- ----------- --------------------
1    60       TEMP                 32767       +DATA/TRISCALDB/TEMPFILE/temp.265.1016190837
2    20       PDB$SEED:TEMP        32767       +DATA/TRISCALDB/FD9AC20F64D244D7E043B6A9E80A2F2F/DATAFILE/pdbseed_temp012019-08-13_11-21-09-am.dbf
3    20       TRISCALPDB:TEMP      32767       +DATA/TRISCALDB/FD9BD2B44413096FE043B6A9E80ABC28/DATAFILE/triscalpdb_temp012019-08-13_11-47-56-am.dbf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the following.

On 2019-08-19 18:00:00 you started a full online database backup that took 5 minutes. This backup included all the datafiles listed above.

Backuppieces created from this operation:

- arch1.bkp - backup of archivelogs that existed before starting the full database backup + the last archivelog that was created as a result of the implicit logswitch
- db1.bkp - backup of datafiles
- arch2.bkp - backup of archivelogs that were created during the full database backup + the last archivelog that was created as a result of the implicit logswitch
- c1.bkp - controlfile autobackup created at the end of the backup process

Then at 2019-08-19 18:10:00 someone dropped the TRISCTALTB tablespace.
At 2019-08-19 18:15:00 a scheduled archivelog backup was started, which took 1 minute, and created the following backuppieces:

- arch3.bkp - backup of archivelogs created since the last backup + the last archivelog that was created as a result of the implicit logswitch
- c2.bkp - controlfile autobackup created at the end of the backup process

At 2019-08-19 18:20:00 you realize that TRISCALTB tablespace is missing. You check the alert log, and see the tablespace was dropped at 2019-08-19 18:10:00. You decide to do an incomplete database recovery and specify the point of time as 2019-08-19 18:09:59, right before the  tablespace was dropped.

You then stop the instance, delete all files, check the backups, start the instance in nomount mode, and restore the controlfile from the latest controlfile backup: c2.bkp. The problem is, that controlfile backup was taken after the TRISCALTB was dropped, so there is no datafile 13 in the list of datafiles.

You perform the restore and recovery until 2019-08-19 18:09:59. This restores all datafiles except datafile 13 from db1.bkp, restore and applies the archivelogs from arch2.bkp and arch3.bkp. When the recovery is complete, you then open the database with `alter database open resetlogs;`.

That is the point where such datafile entries, with `MISSING` in their name are created. Datafile 13 does not exist in the restored controlfile. Datafile 13 exists in the dictionary in SYSTEM tablespace at the point of time it was restored and recovered to. When you open the database, it recognizes the mismatch between the controlfile and the dictionary, and creates an offline datafile entry in the controlfile with the name of `MISSING` and the datafile number (`00013`) under the default location (`$ORACLE_HOME/dbs`). No, RMAN did not restore datafile 13 at all, it is not in the filesystem, datafile 13 is just a controlfile entry at this point.

Even though you had no errors during the restore and recovery, it is not yet complete. If you see these `MISSING` datafiles, you need to restore and recover them.

At this point you can do the following in RMAN:

Restore the datafile:

```
run
{
  set newname for datafile 13 to '+DATA';
  restore datafile 13;
}
```

Switch to the restored copy:

```
switch datafile 13 to copy;
```

Recover the restored datafile:

```
recover datafile 13;
```

Finally bring it online:

```
alter database datafile 13 online;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! it worked here. I didn't know about the command set newname for and I will read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the control files know that the data file should exist, but the data file might not be a part of your backup. Do you have the log from your most recent backup? Does it show that this data file is a part of the backup? What does your RMAN backup script look like? Are you excluding any table spaces from your RMAN backup script?

Comment: No, it is the other way around. Such entries are created when the datafile did not exist in the controlfile, but the dicitonary contained a reference to it. If the controlfile contains a datafile entry, that entry has the correct and full path as well. If OP had no backups of datafile 13 and tried to restore and recover the database, that would have caused other kind of errors.